# Strange camera bug with Google Glass and ZXing

Tags: android, camera, google-glass, zxing

I'm trying to develop a Glassware that will embed ZXing for some *offline* scanning. The barcode scanned will be available as an Intent result in my Activities, and I'll handle it. As I want offline functionnality, I can't use BarcodeEye, which can't be launched without a Wi-Fi connection on my glass. (I have a "no Network Connectivity" alert when I launch it)

Because I'm working on Eclipse ADT, and because all the new releases of ZXing are made with Maven (which is not compatible with ADT, sadly), I'm using the 3.0.0 version.

I've downloaded the core-3.0.0.jar from the Central Maven Repo, and the "Android" project from Github, release 3.0.0.

When I build this (the Android project from ZXing) apk and make it run on my glass, I have two cases:

- The splash screen never disapears, and nothing happens (not even an error in LogCat)
- The camera view is... Well, see by yourself:

[image: Weird Camera Bug]

I have absolutely no idea of where it could come from, and it would take me a whole lot of time to dig into ZXing source code to find the solution. That's why I'm asking your help here. **How can I get rid of this strange glitch with ZXing on Glass?**

BTW, from what I experimented, this is the actual image stripped off the camera, and not a display glitch. Because I tried to scan a barcode, that I put right in front of the glasses, and nothing happened.
Otherwise, the camera works well when I use it to take a simple picture.

Comment: I've tried different SDKs for Google Glass, and I can only recommend this sdk: http://www.scandit.com/developers/ This is not be the answer you're looking for. Back to your problem: I believe you can just build the latest ZXing with maven and just include it in your project as a jar.

Comment: The thing is that the "Android" project is not usable as an APK on the glasses. So I wanted to include it in my Glass project as a dependency and call the scan intent when needed. So I can't build my ZXing Android APK with Maven, it has to be built with Ant on Eclipse.

Comment: I'll take a look a the link you just gave me! I don't mind switching between the two if Scandit is better :)

EDIT: Aw, it's licensed... Bad news :/

Comment: If you go here http://www.scandit.com/pricing/ you can select community edition, which is free.

Comment: I'm on it! I'll tell you how it goes. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I managed to find a port of ZXing WITH intents (it's a fork of BarCodeEye) which seems to work pretty well, whereas Scandit needs a license, and I found it a bit less reactive than ZXing. So in the end I don't think I'm going to use Scandit, but thanks for your help anyway! And I'm still interested by an answer, just to learn a bit more, so I won't delete this post.

Comment: if you're a freelance developer, i highly recommend not to use scandit. it took over a day to get a quote, and the lowest tier they give is 100 devices and only one platform for $3000/y !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this is actually the refresh rate for the camera. By default the camera is initialized to high for the screen to be set correctly. You actually have to manually set the refresh rate to fix this. You will have to modify any camera library you bring in to initialize the camera with these parameters

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(640,360);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

and that should fix your preview for you.

Comment: I'd have never thought of that, but that seems to be possible! I'll check that on Monday, or maybe a bit later. I'll tell you! Cheers !

Comment: Yes it's actually it! I've been using [BarCodeEye](https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye) since then and I noticed a "XE10Workaround" method in the camera manager, containing exactly that. My problem now is that it's quite unresponsive for 1D barcodes on glass, but that's another issue. Cheers!